# How to get list of project domains in Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a cloud function which is sending a welcome email. In this email, I would like to provide a URL to our site. Depending on the project in which the function is called, the URL should change dynamically.

e.g if I call the function in the development project it should go to https://dev.my-site.com, in productions: https://my-site.com

Is there a way to dynamically retrieve a list of the current projects domains from within a firebase function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no API to get a list of the domains associated with Firebase Hosting on the current project. The existing [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest) is purely focused on deployment activities.

Your request is not unreasonable though, so while it isn't currently possible, I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

In the meantime, you'll have to pass in some additional information to the function, or add the necessary information during deployment of the Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, will file that request now!